# wifi videostreaming from laptop to device

Tags: android-wifi

trying  to create a program that works as following .video is captured by web cam of laptop and it is  streamed to android phone using wifi .According to the video displayed, user types some messages and sents back to laptop simultaneously.

- googled and found that making an ad-hoc wireless network will work,but forum 
  discussions   says its not supported by android.want my app to work from 2.2 onwards
- Which Socket communication protocol (UDP or TCP)  protocol should be used to stream video?
- Since want to implement two way communication, which one must be the server (laptop or   mobile device)

Please guide me how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

1. use connectify or any virtual router to get connected to your android phone.so app can be connected with your laptop or desktop.
2. go for UDP its fast and recover data even if it's lost and also use a proper data streaming strategy or a protocol.
3. According to your application design , i will recommend you to make your laptop work as a server. Also it would be best if you choose to use threading in both application and recommend your app to act as server or client as it's required shows more robustness..!